# Issues with Rendering a Bitmap

Tags: c#, canvas, graphics, bitmap, grasshopper

I am currently working on a histogram renderer that renders bitmaps onto the Grasshopper canvas. There are a total of two bitmaps, both of them explained below

`private readonly Bitmap _image;`

and:

`private readonly Bitmap _overlayedImage;`

The `Bitmap` instance with the name `_image` looks like this:

[_bitmap http://puu.sh/6mUk4/20b879710a.png](http://puu.sh/6mUk4/20b879710a.png)

While the `Bitmap` instance with the name `_overlayedImage` looks like this:

[image]

Basically, `_overlayedImage` is a bitmap that is created using the `_image` bitmap, and as the name suggests, overlays the text (that you can see in the image I posted) and adds a black background to it. This is how it is assigned

`_overlayedImage = overlayBitmap(_image, width * 3, height * 3, times, dates, colors);`

(The `* 3` is used to resize the image).

---

An issue I currently have is multi-fold.

Using this method, I am able to render `_image` onto the canvas.

[image]

The code is like this:

```
    protected override void Render(Grasshopper.GUI.Canvas.GH_Canvas canvas, Graphics graphics, Grasshopper.GUI.Canvas.GH_CanvasChannel channel) {
        // Render the default component.
        base.Render(canvas, graphics, channel);

        // Now render our bitmap if it exists.
        if (channel == Grasshopper.GUI.Canvas.GH_CanvasChannel.Wires) {
            var comp = Owner as KT_HeatmapComponent;
            if (comp == null)
                return;

            List<HeatMap> maps = comp.CachedHeatmaps;
            if (maps == null)
                return;

            if (maps.Count == 0)
                return;

            int x = Convert.ToInt32(Bounds.X + Bounds.Width / 2);
            int y = Convert.ToInt32(Bounds.Bottom + 10);

            for (int i = 0; i < maps.Count; i++) {
                Bitmap image = maps[i].overlayedImage;
                if (image == null)
                    continue;

                Rectangle mapBounds = new Rectangle(x, y, maps[i].Width, maps[i].Height);
                mapBounds.X -= mapBounds.Width / 2;

                Rectangle edgeBounds = mapBounds;

                GH_Capsule capsule = GH_Capsule.CreateCapsule(edgeBounds, GH_Palette.Normal);
                capsule.Render(graphics, Selected, false, false);
                capsule.Dispose();
                graphics.DrawImage(image, mapBounds);
                graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, mapBounds);

                // some graphics interpolation and bicubic methods

                y = edgeBounds.Bottom - (mapBounds.Height) - 4;
            }
        }
    }
```

As per what `comp.CachedHeatmaps;` is:

```
    private readonly List<HeatMap> _maps = new List<HeatMap>();

    internal List<HeatMap> CachedHeatmaps {
        get { return _maps; }
    }
```

---

However, whenever I try to use `Render()` on the `_overlayedImage`, I am unable to do so.

I have isolated the issue to the `Render()` method, and it seems this line

`Rectangle mapBounds = new Rectangle(x, y, maps[i].Width, maps[i].Height);` is the main issue, as `maps[i].Width` and `maps[i].Height` returns `1` and `100` respectively, which are coincidentally the dimensions of the legend, which are 100 pixels vertically and 1 pixel horizontally.

---

I apologize for the decently long question, but I don't think I could have explained it any other way.

Comment: Your two bitmaps have different dimensions. Should you use different maps[i].Width/Height to render? (Since your _overlayedImage is 3x the size)

Comment: Interestingly enough when I try to find out the `width` and `height` of `_maps`, my `Render()` doesn't even get called at all, since default Grasshopper behavior doesn't call `Render()` if the dimensions mismatch. Any ideas on how to find the dimensions of `_maps`?

Comment: Oh I figured out how to find out the value.

Comment: Hi Tianyun. You were right, there was a mismatch. I fixed it - thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there are two issues:

In my main method I used `_overlayedImage.Dispose()`, which effectively destroyed the image before it was even displayed onto the canvas.

Also, my issue isolation was also correct. This line resulted in the thing rendering correctly:

`Rectangle mapBounds = new Rectangle(x, y, maps[i].overlayedImage.Width, maps[i].overlayedImage.Height);`

Resulting component:

[image]